# How do I correctly apply a conference/journal paper template in MS Word to correctly use styles, etc.?

Tags: ms-word

I spent a significant amount of time trying to apply a scientific conference paper template, made in Microsoft Word, that I want to document this problem (and my eventual solution), in case someone faces a similar difficulty (and in case I forget how I did it, I can refer back to this). In this particular case, the conference template was [this](http://www.ion.org/plans/upload/PLANSA4Format.doc), but I think many conferences and journals offer similar templates, so this question should have fairly broad interest.

The question is, given this template (which is really not a template in the MS Word sense), how can I create a document that uses the styles defined therein? How can I sure that when I save the document, it will not revert back to some other style definitions defined in Normal.dot?

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word, "templates" are defined in .dot, .dotx, or .dotm files. The .dotx and .dotm formats are for newer versions of Word and the difference lies in whether Macros are disabled or enabled. Despite this definition, some organizations (such as conference organizers or journal publishers) will supply a .doc (or .docx, etc.) file, also calling it a "template" and asking you to use the styles and other formatting elements defined in it. If you were to start editing this file directly and then save it, you might be surprised that the next time you open that document, some of the styles may differ from what you saw when you were initially editing the document. This is because of a clash between the style names provided in the initial file and your Normal.dot template, which is the default template that your instance of MS Word uses. Here are the steps you need to do to avoid this problem:

1. When you first open the "template" supplied by the conference organizer / journal publisher, immediately save this file as a Word template by choosing "Save as" from the Office button (or File-> Save as... in older versions) and selecting .dot, .dotx, or .dotm in the "Save as type" field. Furthermore, you should save this in "Templates" folder for your installation of Word. In most versions, there is a shortcut to this folder in the top of the left panel of the "Save as" window. Give the file some name like "MyConferenceTemplate.dot".

[image]

2. Next, close the .dot (or .dotx, etc.) file that you just saved. This will help avoid that inadvertently that editing the template.
3. Create a new document (by clicking Office button->New or similar). On the left panel of the window that opens, select "My Templates...". You should then see the template which you created in step 1. Select this as the template to apply to your new document.
4. Start editing the newly created file and applying the desired styles...